# Amazon SES fails to deliver emails to office domains

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an `AWS SES` application, which sends an email when an event happens. The mail deliver is successful when I send it to gmail. But, if I want to use my company domain address which is also verified by SES, I do not see any emails in my account. The confusion part is, the sender email (FROM) is my company domain address.

Comment: what is your company mail server, e.g. ActiveDirectory? and is the from address you are sending from the same email address (whether you are sending to the gmail email address or to your company's email address)

Comment: Sending from Gmail To Gmail works. Sending from Gmail to Company Address works. Sending from Company to Gmail address works. But, sending from Company to Company address dosent work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way is to create a SNS subscription and a topic from Amazon console, if you are trying to send e-mails from you application you might have to see if your corporate SMTP server is able to recieve e-mails.
Another simple route is to use "sendgrid" service, this is a paid subscription and it is very easy to use.